# What does "race their flags on the boards" possibly mean?

Tags: expressions

Is there an obvious meaning to this phrase in the following sentence (the context is a motorbike race) :

> This is where the big boys stand out and race their flags on the boards.

How should I interpret it ?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with "on the boards" being used like this. Perhaps, it makes more sense in sailing, where "board" could mean "a distance covered by a vessel in a single tack".

Comment: This not idiomatic English; its source is an [*advertising blurb*](http://toucharcade.com/games/motor-gp-bike-race-pro-super-fast-motorbike-racing) which was clearly NOT written by a native speaker, and there's no telling what the author meant.

Comment: I don't find the expression anywhere except in the motorcycle racing app blurb that the OP is probably reading.  Here's a speculative possibility: in Australian Supercross rules, a black board with a rider's number, along with black flag held stationary, means that that rider has to come in for a pit stop on the next lap.  This could be a "flag on the board". Since managing your pit stops well is essential in a race, then "racing your flags on the boards" could mean that you have to manage your race around your pit stops.

Comment: And then as StoneyB points out, there are plenty of grammatical erros in Zinida Tulchinski's blurb, which suggests that he/she might have made up the term as well.  Since it's the only place I can find the expression, it's likely that StoneyB is right.  My speculation was still creative, though.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The phrase is a metaphor.

The scoreboard of the race will show the flags of the competitors.  As the competitors race, their position, and so their flags, moves on the scoreboard.

Hence a metaphor for the race itself is a race of the flags on the boards.

It is not a common expression and smacks of the hyperbole used by sports commentators.